# Command similar to lndir to update the directory

Tags: unix

The command lndir is used to create a copy of the original directory where files are soft links to the original counterparts. Is there a way to update the directory. e.g If there are new files created in the original directory the command or lndir used with the option should just create new files.

Thanks,
Gudge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [lndir man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lndir)

> If you add files, simply run lndir again. New files will be silently added. Old files will be checked that they have the correct link.

Comment: In case `lndir` is not installed, it is available as a shell script as part of X11: https://opensource.apple.com/source/X11/X11-0.46.4/lndir.sh?txt